# Can Python be invoked against a script file with a parameter-name for the script filepath?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

Does anyone know if the `python3` command on Linux can have some sort of `SOME_NAMED_OPTION=filename.py` after it rather than just calling `python3 filename.py`?

I have a job scheduling tool I'd like to execute a Python script with that's kind of dumb.

It can only run Linux CLI commands `commandname param1 param2 param3` or as `commandname AAA=param1 BBB=param2 CCC=param3`.

There's an existing business convention of putting `filename.py` as param #1 and then just making sure your script has a lot of comments about what the subsequent numerically ordered `sys.argv` list members mean, and you set the scheduling tool into its first mode, so it runs `python3 filename.py world mundo monde`, but it'd be awesome to be able to name the scheduling tool's parameters #2+ so I can write more human-friendly Python programs.

With `python3 -h` I'm not finding a way to give a parameter-name to `filename.py`, but I thought I'd see if anyone else had done it and I'm just missing it.

It'd be cool if I could have my scheduling tool run the a command more like `python3 --scriptsource=filename.py --salut=monde --hola=mundo --hello=world` and then write `filename.py` to use argparse to grab `hola`'s, `hello`'s, and `salut`'s values by name instead of by position.

Comment: Assuming that you are using Bash as your shell, would it be feasible to add a shebang to the Python source file (i.e., have the command `#!python3` as the first line of the Python script)? If so, you could then run it simply as `./filename.py --salut=monde --hola=mundo --hello=world`, without having to explicitly reference the Python interpreter in the shell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a python file to be executed as a script like in the example bellow:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3  # path to python in your system
    
    print('This is a script!')
```

If your python file is named *test.py* you can execute as *./test.py* if the file has permission to be executed. To grant execution permission to your file use the command `chmod +x test.py`

Comment: It might be worth highlighting the shebang portion and how it works. The shebang (`#!/path/to/exectuable`) tells the shell with what command it should execute the script.

Comment: That's interesting ... the scripts my coworker gave me as a template already have the shebang at the top.

Perhaps our job-scheduling tool setups are redundant...

Answer (score 0):

Using the Shebang as suggested by @daniboy000 is the preferred method for doing this, but if for some reason you can't do that, you should be able to do `python3 mycommand --arg1 --arg2=x`

Comment: My comment with `python3 myscript.py --arg1 --arg2=x` is that I can't get my tool to pass `myscript.py` one style and the rest of the arguments another style.  Thanks though.

Comment: ahh. Strange. Well like i said, the shebangs are definitely the first way to go.